# Difference in 3 Angles

Tags: sql, t-sql, degrees

Hoping you all can help with my math mind block I am having.

I have 3 blade pitch angles: (degrees)
B1 = 2.264,   B2 = 2.250,   B3 = 2.258

I am trying to find the difference between all three. As in what is the degree of difference between each.

I am using this SQL formula:

```
ATAN( (SIN([Blade1Position]) + SIN([Blade2Position]) + SIN([Blade3Position])) / 
            (COS([Blade1Position]) + COS([Blade2Position]) + COS([Blade3Position])) 
          ) AS BladePostionMEAN
```

Not sure if this is the right direction but I looking to say; out of these 3 angels they are all off by x-x-number of degrees, when all 3 should be equal.

Comment: This question might be better suited to math.stackexchange, but in an effort to help I think we'll need a bit more info as it's not really clear what you mean by "find the difference between all three."

Do you mean the difference of each from some ideal value, the difference of each from the mean value of all of them, or something else?

Comment: @WurdahMekanik did not know about math.stackexchange. I will give it a go. But I think the difference of each from the mean value of all of them might be the way to go. That I can do. just was in a brain lock.

Comment: in that case, you definitely wouldn't need to mess with any trig functions and could simply find the mean in the traditional way (i.e. summing all the values & dividing by the number of values added, or using the AVG() function in SQL)

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer:

using:

```
IIF(ABS([Blade1Position] - [Blade2Position]) > 180, 360 - ABS([Blade1Position] - [Blade2Position]), ABS([Blade1Position] - [Blade2Position])) AS BladeAngle_diff1
, IIF(ABS([Blade1Position] - [Blade3Position]) > 180, 360 - ABS([Blade1Position] - [Blade3Position]), ABS([Blade1Position] - [Blade3Position])) AS BladeAngle_diff2
, IIF(ABS([Blade2Position] - [Blade3Position]) > 180, 360 - ABS([Blade2Position] - [Blade3Position]), ABS([Blade2Position] - [Blade3Position])) AS BladeAngle_diff3
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).